# When Selenium test execution is triggered in Azure devops server screenshots are not captured for Internet explorer browser

Tags: azure, selenium, azure-devops, internet-explorer-11

We have few test cases automated using Selenium and C#. We need to run our tests in Internet Explorer 11. Test case executes perfectly in local systems but when we do the test run remotely using Azure Devops server test execution happens but screenshots are not captured properly it's coming blank.

Anyone encountered this issue of blank screenshots in IE browsers in Azure devops server?

If tests are executed in Chrome then screenshots are captured perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> When Selenium test execution is triggered in Azure devops server screenshots are not captured for Internet explorer browser

According to your description, it seems this issue is more related to the Internet Explorer 11 settings or any other different on the hosted agent.

Anyway, to resolve this issue, we have to debug the Internet Explorer 11 on the hosted agent. However, we could not access the hosted agent directly, it will be hard to debug it.

As workaround, we could setup private agent:

[How to Set Up a Private Agent in Visual Studio Team Services](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-set-up-a-private-agent-in-visual-studio-tea)

With private agent, we could execute selenium test by the local Internet Explorer 11.